# Filtering a query in Entity Framework based upon a child value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity

I've got a model set up in the Entity Framework (EF) where there are two tables, parent and child, in a one to many relationship.  Where I am having trouble is writing a query with linq where I am trying to retrieve a single instance of the parent while filtering upon a field in the parent and another field in the child.  It would look something like what is listed below:

```
var query = from c in context.ParentTable 
            where c.IsActive == true && c.ChildTable.Name = "abc" 
            select c;
```

Unfortunately when I try this it fails because no field named "Name" appears available via Intellisense when I type c.ChildTable.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct because *c.ChildTable* is not of your *Child* type but *EntityCollection<Child>*. In order to make your query work, you need to modify it like this:

```
var query = from p in context.ParentTable 
            from c in p.ChildTable 
            where p.IsActive == true 
                  && c.Name == "abc" 
            select p;
```